# How do I get the value (original) from this array?

Tags: php, arrays

I get the result in `$list = json_decode($result, true);` I tried to output via `array_column` but nothing comes out.

This is the array:

```
array(95) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["next_episode"]=>
    int(1)
    ["next_episode_at"]=>
    string(29) "2021-04-01T09:00:00.000+03:00"
    ["duration"]=>
    NULL
    ["anime"]=>
    array(12) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(48442)
      ["name"]=>
      string(12) "Shikaru Neko"
      ["russian"]=>
      string(23) "Ругающий кот"
      ["image"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["original"]=>
        string(44) "/system/animes/original/48442.jpg?1615418299"
        ["preview"]=>
        string(43) "/system/animes/preview/48442.jpg?1615418299"
        ["x96"]=>
        string(39) "/system/animes/x96/48442.jpg?1615418299"
        ["x48"]=>
        string(39) "/system/animes/x48/48442.jpg?1615418299"
      }
      ["url"]=>
      string(26) "/animes/48442-shikaru-neko"
      ["kind"]=>
      string(2) "tv"
      ["score"]=>
      string(3) "0.0"
      ["status"]=>
      string(5) "anons"
      ["episodes"]=>
      int(0)
      ["episodes_aired"]=>
      int(0)
      ["aired_on"]=>
      string(10) "2021-04-01"
      ["released_on"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
```

How do I output the value of `$original` from this array?

Comment: like this? `echo $list[0]['anime']['images']['original'];`

Comment: @dehart - You have an accidental `s` on `images` (it's just `image` in the object). You still have > two minutes to fix it. :-)

Comment: @dehart Thkx it's work

Answer (score 0):

because you are using $list = json_decode($result, true) - true means ..

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
**associative**

> When true, JSON objects will be returned as associative
> arrays; when false, JSON objects will be returned as objects. When
> null, JSON objects will be returned as associative arrays or objects
> depending on whether JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY is set in the flags.

```
echo $list['next_episode'];
```

or

```
$list = json_decode($result);
echo $list->next_episode;
```